# Weird Chapter, Section, and Subsection Spacing When Using [H] for Figures and Tables

Tags: spacing, floats, sectioning

When I insert figures into my document that need to be at that exact place (using [H]), then sometimes huge spaces appear under the chapter, section, or subsection headings:

[image]

Is there a way to set a fixed spacing size for all headings of a certain type so this does not happen?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is what you get when you use a book like structure (that attempts to have the same height on all pages) combined with `[H]` "floats". In general never use `[H]` it only gives problems. Use `[htp]` or even `[htbp]` and the figure will come as close to where you put it as possible.

Comment: @daleif I replaced everything with [htp], but there are still different spacings for sections. Its no as extreme as before but it still happens. Also, my figures are not always were they are supposed to be when using [htp]. Is there no simple method to give all sections a fixed size of spacing? Or is there an alternative to [H] that does not screw up the floats as much as [H] does?

Comment: Floats move when there is not enough room for them. That is a fact of life and you will see this is every proffessionel publication ever. Embrace it, don't fight it. If there is stull strange spacing, then provide a full but minimal example that we can use to test. Please replace your images by `\rule{5cm}{5cm}` or similar as we do not have your images